# how to add item to the json file formatted array

Tags: php, json, file, post

I am using using just 1 data to insert in my json file.

```
$data=$_POST['myusernamer'];

$inp = file_get_contents('7players.json');
$tempArray = json_decode($inp);
array_push($tempArray, $data);
$jsonData = json_encode($tempArray);
file_put_contents('7players.json', $jsonData);
```

So this is how my json file looks. I just want to add 1 player at the end.

```
{ 

"players":[
   {

        "name":"Moldova",
        "image":"/Images/Moldova.jpg",
        "roll_over_image":"tank.jpg"
   },
   {

        "name":"Georgia",
        "image":"/Images/georgia.gif",
        "roll_over_image":"tank.jpg"
   },
   {

        "name":"Belarus",
        "image":"/Images/Belarus.gif",
        "roll_over_image":"tank.jpg" 
   },
   {

        "name":"Armenia",
        "image":"/Images/armenia.png",
        "roll_over_image":"tank.jpg"
   },
   {

        "name":"Kazahstan",
        "image":"/Images/kazahstan.gif",
        "roll_over_image":"tank.jpg"
   },
   {

        "name":"Russia",
        "image":"/Images/russia.gif",
        "roll_over_image":"tank.jpg"
   },
  ],


"games" : [ 

    { 

    "matches" : [ 

            {

            "player1id":"*",
            "player2id":"*",
            "winner":"*"
            },

            {
            "player1id":"*",
            "player2id":"*",
            "winner":"*"
            },

            {
            "player1id":"*",
            "player2id":"*",
            "winner":"*"
            },

            {
            "player1id":"*",
            "player2id":7,
            "winner":"*"
            },

            {
            "player1id":"*",
            "player2id":"*",
            "winner":"*"
            },

            {
            "player1id":"*",
            "player2id":"*",
            "winner":"*"
            },

            {
            "player1id":"*",
            "player2id":"*",
            "winner":"*"
            }
        ]
       },

    {

    "matches" : [

            {
            "player1id":"*",
            "player2id":"*",
            "winner":"*"
            },
            {
            "player1id":"*",
            "player2id":"*",
            "winner":"*"
            },
            {
            "player1id":"*",
            "player2id":"*",
            "winner":"*"
            },
            {
            "player1id":"*",
            "player2id":7,
            "winner":"*"
            },
            {           
            "player1id":"*",
            "player2id":"*",
            "winner":"*"
            },
            {
            "player1id":"*",
            "player2id":"*",
            "winner":"*"
            },
            {
            "player1id":"*",
            "player2id":"*",
            "winner":"*"
            },

      ]
    }
  ] 
}
```

My question is, how do I add player at the end? And I would also like to know how to update

```
player1id":"*",
"player2id":"*",
"winner":"
```

in the match array.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just decode your json string and then use array push

```
$tempArray = json_decode($jsonstring, true);
array_push($tempArray, $your_data);
```

For your case

```
    $str = '{ 

"players":[
   {

        "name":"Moldova",
        "image":"/Images/Moldova.jpg",
        "roll_over_image":"tank.jpg"
   },
   {

        "name":"Georgia",
        "image":"/Images/georgia.gif",
        "roll_over_image":"tank.jpg"
   } ]}';


 $arr = json_decode($str, true);
 $arrne['name'] = "dsds";
 array_push( $arr['players'], $arrne );
 print_r($arr);
```

Just check value of print_r($arr); I hope this is what you want. :)

Comment: isn't this gonna fail? I always thought that json_decode is an object representation not an array. You could use true as a second argument thought, so that you would get associative array representation? thanks for explanation :)

Comment: @intelis well said the second parameter is so imprtant. :)

Comment: @chandresh_cool Thanks a lot of replying.. I have doubt..Can I pass just 1 value in a araay,say just the name of player, and leave the rest..Will that make any problems??

Comment: @chandresh_cool Please if you could help me with this..$inp = file_get_contents('7players.json');
     $tempArray = json_decode($inp, true);
     $arrne['name'] = $_POST['myusernamer'];
     array_push( $arr['players'], $arrne );
     $jsonData = json_encode($tempArray);
     $jsonData = json_encode($tempArray);
     file_put_contents('7players.json', $jsonData); It says first argument must be array..they are arrays..What am doing wrong here?

Comment: change your array_push line to this array_push( $tempArray['players'], $arrne );

Comment: @chandresh_cool  Thank you replying..But no chance..My code here.. $inp = file_get_contents('7players.json');
     $tempArray = json_decode($inp, true);
     $arrne['name'] = $_POST['myusernamer'];
     array_push( $tempArray['players'], $arrne );
     $jsonData = json_encode($tempArray);
     file_put_contents('7players.json', $jsonData);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28782/discussion-between-chandresh-cool-and-user2234992)

Answer (score 10):

Adding another player

```
$tempArray = json_decode($inp, true);
array_push($tempArray['players'], array('name' => $data['username'], 'image' => $data['userimage'], 'roll_over_image' => 'tank.jpg'));
```

Updating matches

first match array

```
$tempArray['games'][0]['matches'];
```

second match array

```
$tempArray['games'][1]['matches'];
```

are now simple two dimensional arrays with keys `player1id`, `player2id` and `winner` - it should be easy to update these.
After that you can encode the `$tempArray` back to json.

Comment: Thanks for replying!! What if some values has no values in it.. I don't pass at all..Or I pass with with null values..What happens then..

Answer (score 2):

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
       //first copy your json data  data.json
        $str = file_get_contents('data.json');//get contents of your json file and store it in a string,bro small suggestion never keep any JSON data in ur html file its not safe.always keep json data in external file.
        $arr = json_decode($str, true);//decode it
         $arrne['players'] = "sadaadad";
         $arrne['image'] = "sadaadad";
         $arrne['roll_over_image'] = "sadaadad";
         array_push( $arr['employees'], $arrne);//push contents to ur decoded array i.e $arr
         $str = json_encode($arr);
        //now send evrything to ur data.json file using folowing code
         if (json_decode($str) != null)
           {
             $file = fopen('data.json','w');
             fwrite($file, $str);
             fclose($file);
           }
           else
           {
             //  invalid JSON, handle the error 
           }

        ?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

> In Core PHP

if you want an array on JSON Response. then you can go with this code.

Very simple way, you can use these steps.

1) step you have to convert JSON into an Array using **json_decode()**.

2) use array_merge() method for add new array. if you are interested to add an array.

```
$staff =  json_decode($staffRes ,true);
$driver = ["helpers"=>[id=>1,name=>hep1],[id=>2,name=>hep2]]
$profile= array_merge($staff ,$driver );
```

> In Laravel

```
$staff =  collect($staffRes)->toArray() ; // json() also work here.
$driver = ["helpers"=>[id=>1,name=>hep1],[id=>2,name=>hep2]]
$profile= array_merge($staff ,$driver );
```

> OutPut

```
{
    "error": 0,
    "errmsg": "",
    "response": {
        "id": "NlF4VDMrdEoxM2RCUWkxUE92c29tZz09",
        "type": "DRIVER",
        "driver_name": "Ravi Kumar",     
        "route_name": "Barasat Dak Bungalow",
        "helpers": [
            {
                "helper_id": "K09NTlpHMStiNGlKSGZNMUIyWlAxZz09",
                "helper_name": "Arvind Kumar",
                "helper_mobile": "7777777775",
                "helper_alt_mobile": "7777777777",
                "birth_date": "01-10-2000",
                "address": "Bongaon",
                "id_proof": "123456789-WB",
                "licence_no": null,
                "experience": "2-year",
                "helper_photo":""
            },
            {
                "helper_id": "K29la21vY0VnMTZ5cFY2MU02cm1ZUT09",
                "helper_name": "SUBIR DAS",
                "helper_mobile": "5555555555",
                "helper_alt_mobile": "5555555554",
                "birth_date": "30-10-2019",
                "address": "610/8, ....",
                "id_proof": "NA",
                "licence_no": "NA",
                "experience": "2 years",
                "helper_photo": ""
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this php code

```
 <?php  
 $message = '';  
 $error = '';  
 if(isset($_POST["submit"]))  
 {  
      if(empty($_POST["title"]))  
      {  
           $error = "<label class='text-danger'>Enter details</label>";  
      }  
      else if(empty($_POST["image"]))  
      {  
           $error = "<label class='text-danger'>Enter Posted By</label>";  
      }  
      else  
      {  
           if(file_exists('myfile.json'))  
           {  
                $current_data = file_get_contents('myfile.json');  
                $array_data = json_decode($current_data, true);  
                $extra = array(  
                     'title'               =>     $_POST['title'],  
                     'image'          =>     $_POST["image"],  
                );  
                $array_data[] = $extra;  
                $products['products']=$array_data[];
                $final_data = json_encode($products);  
                if(file_put_contents('myfile.json', $final_data))  
                {  
                     $message = "<label class='text-success'>Added Successfully</p>";  
                }  
           }  
           else  
           {  
                $error = 'JSON File not exits';  
           }  
      }  
 }  
 ?>
```