# How to add element to JSON object using PHP?

Tags: php, json

I have this JSON array, and i want to add another value to it using PHP.

What would be the easiest way to add a ID and Name to this array using PHP.

```
 [
   {
      "id":1,
      "name":"Charlie"
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "name":"Brown"
   },
   {
      "id":3,
      "name":"Subitem",
      "children":[
         {
            "id":4,
            "name":"Alfa"
         },
         {
            "id":5,
            "name":"Bravo"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":8,
      "name":"James"
   }
]
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16184047/4569164

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Simply, decode it using [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

And append array to resulting array.

Again encode it using [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Complete code:

```
<?php
$arr = '[
   {
      "id":1,
      "name":"Charlie"
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "name":"Brown"
   },
   {
      "id":3,
      "name":"Subitem",
      "children":[
         {
            "id":4,
            "name":"Alfa"
         },
         {
            "id":5,
            "name":"Bravo"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":8,
      "name":"James"
   }
]';
$arr = json_decode($arr, TRUE);
$arr[] = ['id' => '9999', 'name' => 'Name'];
$json = json_encode($arr);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($json);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: You answer is correct! But if the question has been already answered on SO, we should mark it as duplicate as done by @phiter fernandes.