# Create a nested JSON object with two laravel eloquent model objects

Tags: php, json, laravel

I'm fairly new to Laravel and right now I'm incorporating a real time notification UI (like sort of a notification reminder drop-down) on a project that I have using Laravel Broadcast. I want to imitate the JSON format from the api that I'm using with the one that is being thrown in once an event is triggered from my logs (appointments) so that it will be easier to manipulate with once throw into the front end. The object that I want to imitate is similar to the one below.

```
[
{
    "id": 39,
    "user_id": 1,
    "campaign_id": 134,
    "lead_id": 12785,
    "date": "2020-04-16 08:43:00",
    "type": "phone-appointment",
    "created_at": "2020-04-05 08:43:38",
    "updated_at": "2020-04-05 08:43:38",
    "lead": {
        "id": 12785,
        "first_name": "First Name",
        "last_name": "Last Name",
        "phone_number": "+12345678911",
        "city": null,
        "car": null,
        "created_at": "2020-02-11 21:33:19",
        "updated_at": "2020-02-11 21:33:19"
    }
]
```

I'm using polymorphic relationship and the api is indexed with this code:

```
public function index()
{
    $userIsSuperAdmin = $this->user->role->contains('name', 'super-admin');
    $userIsManager = $this->user->role->contains('name', 'manager');

    $notifications = Notification::whereNull('read_at')
        ->where(function ($query) use ($userIsSuperAdmin, $userIsManager) {
            if ($userIsSuperAdmin) {
                return true;
            }

            if ($userIsManager) {
                return $query->whereIn('user_id', $this->user->company->users->pluck('id'));
            }

            return $query->where('user_id', $this->user->id);
        })
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->get();

    $result = [];

    foreach ($notifications as $notification) {

        switch ($notification->notificationable_type) {
            case 'appointment';
                $origin = CampaignLeadAppointment::with('lead')
                    ->where('id', $notification->notificationable_id)
                    ->first();

                $result[] = $origin;
                break;
            case 'sms';
                $origin = IncomingSms::with('lead')
                    ->where('id', $notification->notificationable_id)
                    ->first();
                $result[] = $origin;
                break;
            case 'call';
                $origin = IncomingCall::with('lead')
                    ->where('id', $notification->notificationable_id)
                    ->first();
                $result[] = $origin;
                break;
        }
    }

   return $result;

}
```

The events broadcast controller that I made that triggers whenever a new log is created:

```
class NewNotification implements ShouldBroadcast

public $notification;

/**
 * Create a new event instance.
 *
 * @param $notification
 */

public function __construct($notification)
{
    $this->notification = $notification;
}

/**
 * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
 */
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new Channel('new-notification');
}

public function broadcastWith()
{
    if ($this->notification->lead_id != 0) {

        $lead = Lead::where('id', $this->notification->lead_id)->first();

        return array_merge($this->notification->toArray(), $lead->toArray());
    }

    return $this->notification->toArray();

}
```

Here's the data that it throws in to the vue frontend listener (Faulty JSON):

```
[
{
    "id": 13521,
    "user_id": 1,
    "campaign_id": 134,
    "date": "2020-04-16 08:43:00",
    "type": "phone-appointment",
    "created_at": "2020-04-05 08:43:38",
    "updated_at": "2020-04-05 08:43:38",
    "lead_id": 13521,
    "first_name": "First Name",
    "last_name": "Last Name",
    "phone_number": "+12345678911",
    "city": null,
    "car": null,
    }
]
```

I'm trying to use json_encode but all it does is separate both the notification and lead objects and not nest it in. What syntax should I use so that I could nest an eloquent model object to another eloquent model object without using with method?

Comment: Hi, Could you post an example of the faulty json? As far as I can tell now, you might need to load the notification the same way before you throw it as an event/notification like so: `$notification = Notification::with('lead')->find($id); event(new NewNotification($notification));`

Comment: @RobBiermann added the faulty json. I couldn't load it like that because I'm taking in from my notifications table from 3 different logs table using polymorphic relationship. Is it not possible to manipulate the data from the event/notification end?

Comment: Ive tested around, and I think the solution can be rather simple: before you emit the event, and pass the $notification in there, you should be able to call $notification->lead, effectively loading the lead data, and making it available in the model.

Comment: I'm taking in from my notifications table from 3 different logs table using polymorphic relationship: Im not sure why it is not possible, could you elaborate what you tried so far?

Comment: I can't call the lead directly from the  $notification because there is no direct relation between them. The notification controller is structured in a way that it is hidden on the api and what is only actually seen there is the appointment log itself and the lead. The Notification has polymorphic relation with IncomingSMS, IncomingCall and Appointments. Whilst the Appointment mode belongs to a Lead. I can only call a lead through the appointment class and not directly from the notification itself.

Comment: if it helps,  I can include the notification service controller on how the api is thrown. @RobBiermann

Answer (score 0):

Using this instead of array_merge() seems to have answered the question.

```
 public function broadcastWith()
{
    if ($this->notification->lead_id != 0) {

        $lead = Lead::where('id', $this->notification->lead_id)->first();

        $arr = $this->notification->toArray();
        $arr['lead'] = $lead->toArray();

        return $arr;
    }

    return $this->notification->toArray();

}
```

now the events data sent to the front end is structured like this:

```
{
"id": 39,
"user_id": 1,
"campaign_id": 134,
"lead_id": 12785,
"date": "2020-04-16 08:43:00",
"type": "phone-appointment",
"created_at": "2020-04-05 08:43:38",
"updated_at": "2020-04-05 08:43:38",
"lead": {
    "id": 12785,
    "first_name": "First Name",
    "last_name": "Last Name",
    "phone_number": "+12345678911",
    "city": null,
    "car": null,
    "created_at": "2020-02-11 21:33:19",
    "updated_at": "2020-02-11 21:33:19"
}
```

[How to add element to JSON object using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34633272/how-to-add-element-to-json-object-using-php/34633352)

Comment: or rather, in a much simpler note, I just learned that you can append lead to notifications by simply using $lead = $this->notification->lead. and it throw a similar structure with that above.