# accessing a custom REST API returns "Readable Stream" within the body instead of json data

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I've built a custom REST endpoint in a WordPress website using the following code:

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function() {
    register_rest_route('wp/v2', '/all-posts/', array(
      'methods' => 'GET',
      'callback' => 'get_all_posts',
      ''
    ) );
});

function get_all_posts() {

    $api_key = API_KEY;
    $per_page = 50;
    $pages = 20;

    $display_response = json_encode('');

    for($i = 0; $i < $pages; $i++) {
        $page = $i;
        $json = json_decode($display_response, true);
        $documents_url = API_URL;
        $response = wp_remote_get("$documents_url?auth_token=$api_key&page=$page&per_page=$per_page");
        $json .= $response['body'];
        $display_response = json_encode($json);
    }

    return $display_response;
};
```

As you can see, the `API` I'm accessing has a limit of how many records I can access per page, so I have to loop through the pages and combine this data.

I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16184047/how-to-add-item-to-the-json-file-formatted-array) to guide my construction of the returned response.

The problem is that when I try to access with with `fetch` or `wp_remote_get` this response does not deliver useable code.

Particularly when i use the below code:

```
const response = await fetch('https://mydomain/wp-json/wp/v2/all-posts/')
const data = await response.json()
console.log(data)
```

and what was returned was just a long string of all the data I am trying to access, rather than an array of objects as I would expect when getting JSON.

So that is the real question, why is this returning just a long string with the look of JSON but not actual JSON?

And when setting `$posts` within my `php` code to equal the response body, nothing is returned.

Two more notes:

1) There is data being displayed on the WordPress endpoint(`https://mydomain/wp-json/wp/v2/all-posts/`), but it has a lot of `\` in it.
2) I have also tried changing the `return` value at the end of the function to `return json_decode($display_response)` and `return $display_response['body']` which produces the same result.

I am assuming I am adding to the `json` incorrectly so that when it is returned it is returning incorrectly, but I am confused.

Comment: What kind of data does the wp_remote_get return? Is it a JSON endpoint?

Comment: It returns an array of the JSON data, and an Error on Error: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_get/

Comment: Yes, I know. I meant, what exactly does the $response['body'] return? An array? What does the fetched value get decoded to?

Comment: Right, in PHP it returns an error, when accessing via JavaScript in the console (with code above) it returns a long string of all the data.

Comment: The PHP error is: "Operation timed out after 5069 milliseconds with 0 bytes received"

Comment: also when you var_dump the $display_response (on the endpoint) you get string(802005) followed by the string of data

Comment: What do you get when you var_dump the $response from this line: `$response = wp_remote_get(...)`?

Comment: object(WP_Error)#4043 (2) { ["errors"]=> array(1) { ["http_request_failed"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(80) "cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 5069 milliseconds with 0 bytes received" } } ["error_data"]=> array(0) { } }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202687/discussion-between-kostasx-and-logos-164).

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the following code:

```js
const response = await fetch('https://mydomain/wp-json/wp/v2/all-posts/');
const data = await response.json();
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Got it, that returns just a big string instead of what I would expect to be an array of objects

Comment: Updated the question to reflect using this JS instead of the original