# How to append in JSON file at specific position using PHP

Tags: php, json, file, object, append

> **JSON file previous data, where only one record is there**
>
> the JSON data describes an array, and each element of that array is an object.

```
[
   {
      id       : '1'
      name     : 'dfg ggg',
      age      : '17',
      address  : 'somewhere',
      dob      : '10/05/2002'
   }
]
```

> **I just want to append new array with same objects in the top**
>
> then I want to append data like this... in the top...
>
> Here I've appended 2 more records as an array at a top which is first 2 arrays.

```
[
   {
      id       : '3'
      name     : 'sssd dsyz',
      age      : '10',
      address  : 'somewhere',
      dob      : '10/05/2010'
   },
   {
      id       : '2'
      name     : 'Abc Xyz',
      age      : '15',
      address  : 'somewhere',
      dob      : '10/05/2005'
   },
   {
      id       : '1'
      name     : 'dfg ggg',
      age      : '17',
      address  : 'somewhere',
      dob      : '10/05/2002'
   }
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to add item to the json file formatted array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16184047/how-to-add-item-to-the-json-file-formatted-array)

Comment: Sorry, but NO. I want to append data in to the JSON file at the top.

Answer (score 0):

> I've this code in php for appending data array in last postion. But I want to append data array in 0 position.

```
<?php
$current_data = file_get_contents('myfile.json');  
$array_data = json_decode($current_data, true);  
$extra = array(
                'id'       =>   $_POST['id'],
                'name'     =>   $_POST['name'],
                'age'      =>   $_POST['age'],
                'address'  =>   $_POST['address'],
                'dob'      =>   $_POST['dob'],
              );  
                $array_data[] = $extra;  
                $final_data = json_encode($array_data);  
                if(file_put_contents('myfile.json', $final_data))  
                {  
                     $message = "<label class='text-success'>File Appended Success fully</p>";  
                }
?>
```